# Bootstrap 4: How do I get 2 toggle icons on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there a way to get another icon and collapsible dropdown within the navbar in bootstrap 4? I need it to be to the left of the default toggle icon.

Here is my current setup(Ignore the if statements). I'm trying to put the search in its own collapsible dropdown with its own icon on mobile while still having the other nav items in the current dropdown.(I can use the default bootstrap icon for now)

Trying to make mine look similar to monster.com navbar, so take a look at theirs for a reference.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #3c763d!important;">

            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


            <div id="logo">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Company Name</a>
            </div>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">

                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for job">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Location" />
                        <button class="btn btn-seconday " type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/post" class="nav-link">Post a Job</a></li>

                    <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/signup" class="nav-link"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/profile" class="nav-link"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/dashboard" class="nav-link"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/login" class="nav-link"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</strong></a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/logout" class="nav-link"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</strong></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>




    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add second button to your HTML (you can use FontAwesome icon set for search icon instead of pure text).
2. Add `right: 5rem` to your second button.
3. Divide your navbar to two `divs` with different IDs (for search and navbar links).
4. Add different `data-target` attributes to your buttons.
5. You are good to go.

```css
.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-custom {
  right: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #3c763d!important;">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right navbar-toggler-custom" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Search
    </button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div id="logo">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Company Name</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto">

        <form class="form-inline">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for job">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Location" />
          <button class="btn btn-seconday " type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ml-auto ml-auto"><a href="/post" class="nav-link">Post a Job</a>
        </li>

        <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
          <a href="/signup" class="nav-link"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a>
        </li>

        <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'user'" class="nav-item">
          <a href="/profile" class="nav-link"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
        </li>

        <li v-if="user_logged && user_type === 'company'" class="nav-item">
          <a href="/dashboard" class="nav-link"><strong>Employer Dashboard</strong></a>
        </li>

        <li v-if="!user_logged" class="nav-item">
          <a href="/login" class="nav-link"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</strong></a>
        </li>

        <li v-if="user_logged" class="nav-item">
          <a href="/logout" class="nav-link"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</strong></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


</div>
```

Comment: So that solves the problem for the mobile collapse but now my alignment isn't working when its not on mobile. The form isn't centered anymore and the other nav items aren't pushed to the right. Any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: Items now are pushed to the right, but I'm afraid I don't know how to center your search form because this two navbar has 100% width because of Bootstrap styles.

Comment: You can try add `#navbarNav { width: 80%; }` to center search form but i don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: I'll mess around with it. Thanks for the solution on the 2nd icon!